# How to assert_select a class in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails 4.2 for my project but I can't figure out how to check the absence of a particular class. I tried using `assert_select 'p.class_name', false` and `assert_select '.class_name', false`. It is giving the same error:

```
ArgumentError: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1)
```

Also when I am doing

```
puts assert_select 'p', :attributes => {:class => 'class-name'}
```

it is selecting all the p tags which should not be done.

Also when I was checking the presence of text inside a class by doing something like this:

```
assert_select 'p.class_name', 'Hello_world'
```

It was giving the same error.

But then I tried to do

```
assert_select 'p', 'Hello-world'
```

it was working correctly.

So at last, how to assert_select a class in rails 4.2?

Comment: Did you try this ? assert_select('p', 'Hello-world')

Comment: @sam, as I said in the question assert_select('p', 'Hello-world'), is working perfectly. But my question is how to select a particular class for tasks like checking the number of elements, the presence of elements, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrarily complex assertions on HTML, use my `assert_xpath`. The first step would be to isolate the container of your `<p>`. Let's assume it's in an `<article>`, so use an XPath of `//article`. Then call `refute_xpath` with an XPath of `p[ contains(@class, "class-name") ]`. Put them together like this:

```
get :action

assert_xpath '//article' do
  refute_xpath 'p[ contains(@class, "class-name") ]'
  assert_xpath 'p[ "Hello World" = text() ]'
end
```

XPath notation can be as complex and elaborate as a relational database query, unlike the CSS selectors that `assert_select` uses.

Paste my methods into your `test_helper.rb` file:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def assert_xml(xml)
    @xdoc = Nokogiri::XML(xml, nil, nil, Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::STRICT)
    refute_nil @xdoc
    return @xdoc
  end

  def assert_html(html=nil)
    html ||= response.body
    @xdoc = Nokogiri::HTML(html, nil, nil, Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::STRICT)
    refute_nil @xdoc
    return @xdoc
  end

  def assert_xpath(path, replacements={}, &block)
    @xdoc ||= nil  #  Avoid a dumb warning
    @xdoc or assert_html  #  Because assert_html snags response.body for us
    element = @xdoc.at_xpath(path, nil, replacements)

    unless element
      complaint = "Element expected in:\n`#{@xdoc}`\nat xpath:\n`#{path}`"
      replacements.any? and complaint += "\nwith: " + replacements.pretty_inspect
      raise Minitest::Assertion, complaint
    end

    if block
      begin
        waz_xdoc = @xdoc
        @xdoc = element
        block.call(element)
      ensure
        @xdoc = waz_xdoc
      end
    end

    return element
  end

  def refute_xpath(path, replacements={}, &block)
    @xdoc ||= nil  #  Avoid a dumb warning
    @xdoc or assert_html  #  Because assert_html snags @response.body for us
    element = @xdoc.at_xpath(path, nil, replacements)

    if element
      complaint = "Element not expected in:\n`#{@xdoc}`\nat xpath:\n`#{path}`"
      replacements.any? and complaint += "\nwith: " + replacements.pretty_inspect
      raise Minitest::Assertion, complaint
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to use assertions like checking the presence of the class or count of the class?

Comment: XPath can do anything, but the only thing it _can't_ do is match one class in isolation from others in the same class="" tag. If you wrote `<div class="a b">`, an XPath of `//div[ "a" = @class ]` would fail, where a CSS selector of `div.a` would pass. That's why my example used `contains(@class, "a")`. From here, read an XPath tutorial for advanced predicates such as `//article[ 42 = count(p[ contains(@class, "a") ]) ]`.

Comment: I'm glad you like `assert_xpath`; I will see if I can publish it, after I make it compatible with `assert_select`, so one can nest the other.

Comment: One more detail:  You can write `assert_xpath 'p[ "Hello World" = text() ]'` as `assert_xpath 'p[ $text = text() ]', text: 'Hello World'`. This simplifies if your matched text is long, or from a variable, or contains a quote `"`.

Comment: Actually, I also found a way to check the absence of a class name. I used `selector = css_select 'p.class_name'` and then do `assert_equal selector.size, 0` and it works perfectly.

Comment: Use the `count:` option set to `0`. Here's an example from my current project: `assert_select 'li', :text => /Phone number/, :count => 0`.

Comment: Yeah, it works also, but the thing is that we have to find the text inside the element and then write the assert_select. But if I have to directly write the class name with the tag I can't write, it would definitely give an error. something like this: `assert_select 'li.class_name', :count => 0`